# Ring of fractions problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> How do I can determine the ring of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ ?

I don't know the process that I have to follow for do it.

Comment: What definition do you have for the ring of fractions? Are you familiar with the universal property characterization?

Comment: I think that I have to show the form of the ring of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$[X]. Other doubt, how do I can determine the ring of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$[X] x $\mathbb{Z}$[X] or $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$[X] for example?

Comment: Not, I am sure that it is $\mathbb{Z}$[X]

Comment: You can't determine *the* ring of fractions of $\mathbb Z[X]$ because there are *many* rings of fractions of $\mathbb Z[X]$.

Answer (score 3):

If $R$ is an integral domain, then $Q(R[x])=Q(R)(x)$. This can be seen by comparing the elements (probably others will explain this to you here). In particular, $Q(\mathbb{Z}[x])=\mathbb{Q}(x)$, the field of [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function)s in one variable with rational coefficients.

Alternatively and less cumbersome, one can check that both fields satisfy the same universal property: First remark that an element in a field extension of $Q(R)$ is transcendental over $Q(R)$ if and only if it is transcendental over $R$ (just clear denominators). Thus, if $K$ is a field, then

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
\hom(Q(R)(x),K) &\cong& \{\phi \in \hom(Q(R),K), ~t \in K \text{ transcendental over } \phi\}\\& \cong& \{\psi \in \hom(R,K) \text{ injective},~ t \in K \text{ transcendental over } \psi\}\\ & \cong& \{\theta \in \hom(R[x],K) \text{ injective}\} \\& \cong& \hom(Q(R[x]),K) \end{array}$$